# Cannot Subscribe to Notify Characteristic in iOS CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have successfully connected to BLE devices using the same code, but this device is not letting me subscribe.  It's frustrating because I cannot figure out how to get a meaningful error message.

There is a Read/Notify/Indicate characteristic that I am attempting to listen to.  The code I send is:

```
peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
```

my listener is:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if ((error) != nil) {
            NSLog("Error changing notification state: " + error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        if characteristic.isNotifying {
            NSLog("Notification Updated")
        }
    }
```

The error I get is:

> Error changing notification state: Unknown ATT error.

I have downloaded another app that interfaces with this device successfully, so I know that the hardware is functioning properly.

I don't know if there is some sort of encryption or other setting that needs to be sent to allow communication with this device.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `characteristic.properties` ?

Comment: There are three properties for the characteristic: Read, Notify and Indicate.